# Not able to download the excel while using response.flush for each row

Tags: asp-classic, out-of-memory, buffer, response

(Its an primitive code and its working correctly for around 10000 rows)

```
fileName = excelTemplate+".xls"
Response.Write "<html><body><table>"
For Loop for more then 150000 Rows 
{
    Response.Write "<tr><td>..........</td></tr>"
}
Response.Write "</table></body></html>"
Response.AddHeader "content-disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & fileName & ""
Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"           
Response.Flush
```

I am getting Buffer size error (Execution of the ASP page caused the Response Buffer to exceed its configured limit.)

I tried Response.Flush inside the loop:

```
For Loop for more then 150000 Rows 
{
    Response.Write "<tr><td>..........</td></tr>"
    Response.Flush
}
```

Now I am not getting the size limit issue but not able to download the excel..(All the output is rendered on the web page)

After going through some blogs I found tht another fix for this issue is to increase the buffer size from IIS but just wanted to know if there is some othr alternative to this issue..

Comment: Does this error occur in IIS? If so, what version of IIS is being used?

Comment: @John I am using IIS 7

Comment: Have  you tried to turn off buffer instead of flushing? In your asp page add `<%Response.Buffer = False%>`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to move the Response.ContentType, Response.Charset & Response.AddHeader before the first Response.Write

```
<%
    Response.Buffer = True
    ...
    fileName = excelTemplate+".xls"
    Response.AddHeader "content-disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & fileName & ""
    Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"           
    Response.Write "<html><body><table>"
    For Loop for more then 150000 Rows 
    {
        Response.Write "<tr><td>..........</td></tr>"
        Response.Flush
    }
    Response.Write "</table></body></html>"
    Response.Flush  
%>
```